# Can I declare 2 background images but not at the same time in CSS?

Tags: css

I want 2 random background images for the tops and bottoms of my `<body>`. There are 4 potential bg images for the top of my page and 4 for the bottom.  I'll use a function in php in my html to choose a random top image class and random bottom image class.

I know I can do:
`background-image:url(/images/background/background-top-0.jpg),url(/images/background/background-bottom-0.jpg) ;`

Is there a way to add a second background image to an already declared background image? Ideally I'd like:

```
<body class="bg1 bg2">....</body>



.bg1{
    background-image:url(/images/background/background-top-0.jpg);
}
.bg2{
    background-image:inherit, url(/images/background/background-bottom-0.jpg);
}
```

At the moment my css looks like :

```
.bg1.bg2{
    background-image:url(/images/background/background-top-0.jpg),url(/images/background/background-bottom-0.jpg) ;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
    width:100%;
    background-position: center 110px, center bottom 80px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #128bd0;
}
```

Comment: In case of that, `bg2` will have precendence over `bg1`. What do you really want to achieve?

Comment: I want 2 background images in one div, one at the top and one at the bottom.

Comment: You can't. Either you pre-render the background image to merge 2 image into 1. Or you use 2 div with 50% height right inside body.

Comment: oh really?  Oh I cant do that, because I need the middle of the page to be just a background colour, not them both to be stretched.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/t6bfexaj/1/. It's responsive, so yes, it'll would work with unknown dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could apply one background image to `<html>` and one to `<body>`.
The background classes can be used either on the html or on the body

### Example

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.bg1 {
  background: url(http://www.placehold.it/500X50/FF0000) no-repeat;
}
.bg2 {
  background: url(http://www.placehold.it/500X50/FF9900) no-repeat;
}
html.bg {
  background-position: center top;
  background-color: #EEE;
}
body.bg {
  background-position: center bottom;
}
```

```html
<html class="bg bg1">

<body class="bg bg2">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: works great thank you!  I was starting to declare all the possible combinations of bg images in my css there, saved me some time, cheers.

Comment: @Nicola - this is certainly easier :D. I was a bit worried about IE behaviour, but this works just fine in IE 6 +

Answer (score 0):

you can use pseudo element for giving background

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(http://placeimg.com/640/480/tech);
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: '';
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
div:before {
  background: url(http://placeimg.com/640/480/any);
  top: 0
}
div:after {
  background: url(http://placeimg.com/640/480/any);
  bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Good solution, but would this work with unknown heights? Plus I need to have the bit in the middle of the 2 images blue.  SO atm I have `.body-bg.background0{
    background-image:url(/images/background/background-top-0.jpg),url(/images/background/background-bottom-0.jpg) ;
    background-size: contain;
    width:100%;
    background-position: center 110px, center bottom 80px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #128bd0;`

Comment: Updated my question to include above comment

Comment: Damn, I don't know how to insert snippet. Lol.